# How to send phone link in facebook messenger bot button?

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger, facebook-messenger

I am trying to send a link of the form "tel:xxxxxxxxxx" to the button template in facebook messenger platform API. I am getting an error that the url is of invalid type.

Is there any way of sending the telephone link using the messenger platform API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook released an update to the button template recently. You can now specify type = phone_number . Pay load should be the phone number (prefixed by +, isd code and area code. Example +15555555555).

You can find more info here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/button-template

Guru